# Bulk collect into two or more variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to fetch three variables using Bulk collect while looping through a cursor. Is it possible? Please see below query (assume variables are declared)

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR recCurosr
    IS
        SELECT t1.name,t2.value1, t2.value2
        FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2
        WHERE  t1.pk = t2.pk;

BEGIN
    OPEN recCurosr;
    LOOP
        FETCH recCurosr BULK COLLECT INTO var1, var2, var3;
        BEGIN
            FORALL i IN 1 .. var1.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                UPDATE table1
                SET    value1= var2,
                WHERE  value1= var3
                AND    pk = var1;
```

Comment: Yes: [see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-6E09E4FC-28C0-43C8-9E7C-A54D6398D1DE__BABJCBGD)

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks

Comment: The `forall` statement processes all rows returned by `recCurosr` the first time around the loop. What is there for the rest of the loop to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cursor selects data from differen tables you need:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT 'name1', 1, 2 FROM dual;

   TYPE abc IS RECORD ( -- define a record type record 'abc'
      name      VARCHAR2 (100),
      value1    NUMBER,
      value2    NUMBER
   );
   myAbc       abc; -- declare an object with type 'abc'

   TYPE abcTab IS TABLE OF abc; -- define a table type 'abcTab'
   myAbcTab    abcTab; -- declare an object with type 'abcTab'

BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO myAbcTab;
   FOR i IN myAbcTab.FIRST .. myAbcTab.LAST LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(myAbcTab(i).name);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

If you only need all columns from a single table you can use `myAbcTab table1%ROWTYPE;` instead